# JLabel Icon not updating with setIcon (or other redundancies)

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel

Two different versions of code I'm using, as noted, the first one works fine, without any problems what so ever, the second one, the only thing that doesn't happen is the updating of the image (have verified through step debugging and debug printing to verify all values and conditionals by hand)

```
            /* properly updates dice[] JLabel icons */

            for (int i = 0; i < game.getToRoll(); i ++){
                    //sets rolled dice to actual values
                    dice[i].setIcon(dicePic[(game.getDice(i).getFaceValue())]);    
            }

            /* loops properly, generates properly, does not update icons */

            Die x = new Die();
            int animate = 0;

            while(animate < 10){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
                            x.roll();

                            if (i <= (game.getToRoll() -1))
                                    dice[i].setIcon(dicePic[x.getFaceValue()]);                            
                            else   
                                    dice[i].setIcon(dicePic[0]);
                    }
                    panel[1].repaint();
                    panel[1].validate();

                    animate++;
                    try{
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
```

I've been looking around for some kind of idea of what it is that's causing the problem, and I've not run into anything other than that "sometimes repaint and validate will fix things that don't work."

As stated above, debug is giving me the greenlight on code flow working entirely as expected, just null image icons in the second example.

Comment: Don't forget next time to add the [tag:java] tag as that's more important than any other tag for this question. I've so added it.

Comment: There is no need for the repaint() and revalidate() because a component will do that automatically when the icon is changed. Also, the proper order is revalidate() and repaint() because you first need to invoke the layout manager before repainting a component.

Comment: There may be no need, but I've found threads on here about Swing not working as expected and using either-and-or-both of these sometimes fixes it.  However, thanks for the information on it, better to know what I'm doing than applying blind fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `Thread.sleep(100);` The icon does change but you don't see the change because you blocked the UI thread.

So the rule is: **never sleep the EventDispatchThread!**

My advice is to use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```
new javax.swing.Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        //do an icon change
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I tried that originally, and it seemed like the timer object was blocked from occurring due to trying to use a while loop conditioned against the animate counter, so once the loop hit, nothing else would happen, despite the timer coming first.

I'll gladly try to (re)implement a timer, but I don't understand why temporarily stopping the thread doesn't update the icons at any point.

I also don't understand why my previous timer implementation didn't work, my understanding of normal code flow is fine, but it feels like things in swing queue instead of execute.

Comment: I have to refactor the code to implement this new usage of the timer, and I'm encapsulating it in its own method, but the method is giving "cannot convert from void to timer."  Alternatively, is there any way to self reference this new timer, as the only way I can think to implement it without going back to the method that previously didn't work is to stop the timer from within itself.

Comment: Eh, whatever, using a timer worked, but implementing it as suggested didn't.  So thanks for getting me to abandon something that I've yet to be taught why it wouldn't work, and giving me cause to have to debug to getting it to work.